# How can I write "unit" tests for Shake rules or actions?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I am writing specialised rules and oracles for Shake and I would like to write tests for those functions. How can I do that in Shake? I did not find any simple to use `actionToIO` function that could do the job.

For example, I would like to test the behaviour of the following :

```
checkGitWorkDirIsClean = do
  Stdout out <- cmd "git" [ "status", "-s", "-uno" ]
  pure $ null $ filter (/= "") (lines out)
```

so I could create prepare directories containing minimalistic git data and test the function against those directories.

Comment: I had a look at Shake's source code and it seems tests all rely on setting up some directory and running tests with `shakeXXX ...` so that everything happens in IO. I wrote a couple tests following that strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, testing build systems is hard. Shake has [various linting related features](https://shakebuild.com/lint) that are probably the best way to the the entirety of the build system.

For testing small fragments, it's best if you can make them in `IO` rather than `Action`. In the above case, `cmd` can be run in both the `Action` and `IO` monads, so testing it in `IO` is probably much easier.

If you do have fragments in `Action` the only way to drive that through a Shake build system is using something like the `shake` function. If you want to do so in a consistent way, often setting `shakeFiles` to `/dev/null` can be useful, as that will cause Shake not to write to a database, so every run will be as though Shake was starting from a clean slate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil! I have had a look at Shake's (impressive) set of tests and tried the later approach, but working in a per-test temporary directory, as I am using also `git` which needs a prepared directory. The `/dev/null` trick sounds interesting though. The tests are a bit clunky and verbose but at least they provide some safety.